# How do I run a php script in the background of another php script?

Tags: php, ajax

This has been a difficult problem to search for, as all search results describe AJAX requests from javascript. Technically AJAX from javascript COULD solve my issue, but I'd prefer this to be solved purely server side using PHP.

Here's a breakdown of what's going on so far. I've simplified the code a lot.

CustomerOrderForm.php:

```
<form action="CreateOrder.php" method="post" onsubmit="this.submitButton.disabled = true;">
  <input name="first">
  <input name="second">
  <button type="submit">Place Order</button>
</form>
```

CreateOrder.php

```
<?php
basicOrderProcesses($_POST['first'],$_POST['second']);
header("Location: PaymentMethod.php?first=$_POST['first']&second=$_POST['second']");
slowOrderProcesses($_POST['first'],$_POST['second']);
die();

function basicOrderProcesses(){
  //Code that is absolutely essential to processing payment
}
function slowOrderProcesses(){
  //Very time consuming code that I'd rather the customer doesn't have to wait for
}
```

PaymentMethod.php

```
<h1>Please Select Your Payment Method</h1>
...
//You get the idea
```

I thought it was working fine, but as `slowOrderProcesses()` got bigger, the code ran slower. I see now that it never was running in the background, and the page isn't redirecting until `slowOrderProcesses()` is completed.

If CreateOrder.php were running in javascript, I could easily write an AJAX solution like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp). But it's running in pure php. What's the equivalent php solution? Remember, I need the slow processes to run while the customer is choosing a payment method. (And maybe even continue to run after the customer has paid, if the customer is fast enough.)

I'm hoping the solution won't require too much rewriting, but I gotta do what I gotta do. (I try to avoid installing libraries if I can help it.)

Comment: You need multi-threading. "Off-the-shelf PHP builds from package managers do not support multi-threading. "  (https://medium.com/@rossbulat/true-php7-multi-threading-how-to-rebuild-php-and-use-pthreads-bed4243c0561)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible in a webserver, but you could check the http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php. I would use Ajax, I don't see the problem, every browser supports javascript...

Comment: Can you split the call from the javascript into two - make one AJAX call for the essential  stuff and another for the slow stuff. I do that successfully in another similar context. Because AJAX is async you can fire them off one after the other and they run in parallel.

Comment: @Nikkorian if you wrote that as an answer, I'd definitely give it an up vote. It's probably what I'll end up doing. I just want to hear out my other options first. (And if I end up doing it, I'll give it the green tick.)

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers thanks - I am usually reluctant to fire off answers rather than comments. But seeing you asked...

Comment: @Nikkorian I make no predictions about how the rest of the community will respond to your answer, but as promised, it's got an up vote from me.

Comment: The AJAX solution is certainly much simpler than getting into multi-threaded php

Comment: @Nikkorian I probably should be looking this up myself, but if I make an AJAX call then close the browser, does the process still run after I've disconnected? Suppose, for example it's a 5 minute script and I close 30 seconds into it.

Comment: I would expect the php process to continue to run, but closing the browser will kill off the javascript socket that's waiting for a reply. I don't think that the server would detect the missing socket until it tries to reply. But I am not certain.

Comment: @Nikkorian Perfect. The long processes don't need a reply. They're just updating lots of databases. The customer doesn't need to know whether or not it has been successful. Only I need to know.

Comment: If you are working with a local server (localhost) while developing, check this by writing an infinite loop in the php, kill the browser, then watch the process activity. I predict that the server/php activity will remain high until you restart the browser.

Comment: ... meaning it's not interested in the presence of the socket until it finishes its task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the call from the javascript into two - make one AJAX call for the essential stuff and another for the slow stuff. I do that successfully in another similar context. Because AJAX is async you can fire them off one after the other and they run in parallel.